# (amplify-kotlin) Unable to redirect to custom URL scheme

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin

I am trying to integrate Amplify federated identity auth mechanism but no success. Following the instructions specified in the documentation at AWS site.

Below is the intent configuration:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="federatedidentity" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity></application>
```

The application launches the AWS hosted UI page but unable to redirect to the native app. While debugging the browser window (hosted UI) I see below warning:

Navigation is unreachable: federatedidentity://callback?code=auth-code-here

Can someone please assist.

Comment: Changing the action MAIN to VIEW and adding category DEFAULT resolved the issue <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />